HonKit generate epub file summary problem
This is the SUMMARY.file
# Summary

## 第 1 章 瞭解 Java
* [第 1 章 瞭解 Java](docs/CH01.md)
    * [1.1　什麼是 Java](docs/CH01.md## 1.1　什麼是 Java)
    * [1.2　Java 的特性](docs/CH01.md## 1.2　Java 的特性)
    * [1.3　如何學習 Java](docs/CH01.md## 1.3　如何學習 Java)
    * [1.4　接下來的主題](docs/CH01.md## 1.4　接下來的主題)

## 第 2 章 入門準備
* [第 2 章 入門準備](docs/CH02.md)
    * [2.1 下載、安裝、瞭解 JDK](docs/CH02.md## 2.1 下載、安裝、瞭解 JDK)
    * [2.2 設定 Path 與 Classpath](docs/CH02.md## 2.2 設定 Path 與 Classpath)
    * [2.3 第一個 Java 程式](docs/CH02.md## 2.3 第一個 Java 程式)
    * [2.4 選擇開發工具](docs/CH02.md## 2.4 選擇開發工具)
    * [2.5 接下來的主題](docs/CH02.md## 2.5 接下來的主題)

## 第 3 章 語法入門
* [第 3 章 語法入門](docs/CH03.md)
    * [3.1 第一個 Java 程式](docs/CH03.md## 3.1 第一個 Java 程式)
    * [3.2 在文字模式下與程式互動](docs/CH03.md## 3.2 在文字模式下與程式互動)
    * [3.3 資料、運算](docs/CH03.md## 3.3 資料、運算)
    * [3.4 流程控制](docs/CH03.md## 3.4 流程控制)
    * [3.5 接下來的主題](docs/CH03.md## 3.5 接下來的主題)

However after the epub file is generated, there is some unexpected numbers in the summary page shown below
enter image description here
enter image description here
Is there something wrong with the format of my SUMMARY.file?
Have been checking with the HonKit document's example but still couldn't figure out the problem.
# Summary

### Part I

* [Part I](part1/README.md)
    * [Writing is nice](part1/README.md#writing)
    * [HonKit is nice](part1/README.md#honkit)
* [Part II](part2/README.md)
    * [We love feedback](part2/README.md#feedback)
    * [Better tools for authors](part2/README.md#tools)

# Summary

### Part I

* [Part I](part1/README.md)
    * [Writing is nice](part1/README.md#writing)
    * [HonKit is nice](part1/README.md#honkit)
* [Part II](part2/README.md)
    * [We love feedback](part2/README.md#feedback)
    * [Better tools for authors](part2/README.md#tools)

